# ruby hash swap values from one key to another

Tags: ruby, hash, dictionary, key-value, inject

Does anyone have Ruby advice on how would I go about re-mapping the values within a hash to different keys? Say I have this

```
from => {"first"=>30, "wanted"=>27, "second"=>45, "subject"=>68, "present"=>85}
```

and wanted to get this (i.e., values for "present","first" and "subject","second" have been switched):

```
to => {"first"=>85, "wanted"=>27, "second"=>68, "subject"=>45, "present"=>30}
```

I want to do this over a large data set.

Comment: I'm guessing you have an algorithm for the remap, so, from my opinion, the best way to do this would be to write a script for the remap yourself. I don't really see a challenge in this

Comment: you do not describe which is the key switch policy...

Answer (score 3):

```
# this is your starting hash:
from = {"first"=>30, "wanted"=>27, "second"=>45, "subject"=>68, "present"=>85}
# this is your replacement mapping:
map = {'present' => 'first', 'subject' => 'second'}
# create complete map by inverting and merging back
map.merge!(map.invert)
# => {"present"=>"first", "subject"=>"second", "first"=>"present", "second"=>"subject"} 
# apply the mapping to the source hash:
from.merge(map){|_, _, key| from[key]}
# => {"first"=>85, "wanted"=>27, "second"=>68, "subject"=>45, "present"=>30}
```

Comment: thank you. This is part of a much larger problem and I was getting caught up on this remapping. I think this solution will work elegantly. Awesome!

Comment: @user877961 you should mark the answer if you dont need any more tips

Answer (score 2):

You don't provide enough context, but you could do something like

```
 to = Hash[from.keys.zip(from.values_rearranged_in_any_way_you_like)]
```

Edit: `from.values_rearranged_in_any_way_you_like` is supposed to be `from.values` sorted in the way you need (I'm assuming you do have a desired way to sort them for rearrangement).

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```
keys = @hash.keys
values = @hash.values
```

then you could swap entries of the 'values' array (or 'keys' array)

```
values[0], values[4] = values[4], values[0]
```

...

or if you only wanted to shift em up by one item:

```
values.rotate (ruby 1.9)
```

you can also perform push/pop, shift/unshift operations or sort the values
To create the hash do:

```
hsh = Hash.new
keys.size.times do |i|
  hsh[ keys[i] ] = values[i]
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, here's a simple little algorithm. I don't know how efficient it would be, but it should work.

```
class Hash
    def swap_vals!(new_key_maps)
        new_key_maps.each do |key1, key2|
            temp = self[key1]
            self[key1] = self[key2]
            self[key2] = temp
        end
    end
end
```

Comment: why not use self[key1], self[key2] = self[key2], self[key1]

Answer (score 0):

Keep it simple, use merge:

```
from => {"first"=>30, "wanted"=>27, "second"=>45, "subject"=>68, "present"=>85}
to => {"first"=>85, "wanted"=>27, "second"=>68, "subject"=>45, "present"=>30}

from.merge(to)
# => {"first"=>85, "wanted"=>27, "second"=>68, "subject"=>45, "present"=>30}
```

Not sure you should be remapping enormous hashes in ruby though.